# How to generate a website from GitHub wiki pages

Tags: github, documentation, wiki, documentation-generation, github-pages

I've used GitHub pages to generate a beautiful website for my project ([this one](http://owner.aeonbits.org)). Now I want to keep the documentation of my project up to date, and having everything in a single README.md file is probably not scalable to the many features we are adding.

So, I thought that the best place to keep the documentation is the GitHub wiki, but I'd like to integrate the wiki to the gh-pages generated site, keeping the beautiful layout.

How would I take the GitHub wiki and generate an HTML web site with a customizable layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example URL for a wiki:

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki

On the same page you will find a clone link:

https://github.com/golang/go.wiki.git

Then run the Markdown files through [Hugo](//github.com/gohugoio/hugo) or even create a new repository
to the host site based on the Wiki.

Answer (score 2):

You could include your wiki as `subtree`.

BTW, GitHub Pages now no longer need the `gh-pages` branch. Create a repository named `your-user-name.github.io`; it will automatic generate to a website. See [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) for more detail.

Comment: There is a difference between a _user_ page (using `*.github.io` method) and a _project_ page (using `gh-pages` method), though.